# Add additional entry fields to backend search

Tags: craft3, search, entry, field, admin

The search field in the craft backend entry section searches the title and slug field by default. Is it possible to add custom entry fields to this search function (in my case e.g. a custom item number or a field with additional keywords)?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this plugin - https://plugins.craftcms.com/easy-search

Comment: It looks to me like Craft's default search also includes other fields, such as matrix fields. Also, when you define the field there's a checkbox entitled:  _Use this field’s values as search keywords?_ So maybe make sure that you have checked that box. This is with Craft CMS 3.4.20